# How to make this loop faster

Tags: r, loops

it takes about an hour to this loop. Is there any way make this faster?

```
l <- 2

while (l < 300001) {
  VV[1,l] = log(b+(l-1) * 0.001-0.0005) + k + 
    beta * (1-delta) * (1-p * sum(Pr[1,(1:l)])) * V[1, l] + 
    beta  *(1-delta) * p * sum((V[1,] * Pr[1,])[(l+1):300001])
  l = l + 1
}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example and rephrase your question accordingly.

Comment: Have a look at https://adv-r.hadley.nz/perf-improve.html

Comment: It seems that the calculation can be done without a loop. You should try doing it as a vector/matrix calculation. Or provide some sample data so that others can try.

Answer (score 1):

If on *nix (Linux, Unix, macOS, ...) you can use `parallel` processing:

```
library(parallel)

VV <- matrix(ncol = 300001)
mclapply(2:300001, function(l){
  VV[1,l] <<- log(b+(l-1) * 0.001-0.0005) + k + beta * (1-delta) * (1-p * sum(Pr[1,(1:l)])) * V[1,l]+beta  *(1-delta) * p * sum((V[1,] * Pr[1,])[(l+1):300001])
  }, mc.cores = 5)
```